# CSS Dropdown Menu On :Hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, css-transitions

If I "unhover" previously hovered dropdown menu and then fast enought hover the space it was shown at back, dropdown will show back. Is there a way to avoid this behaviour or at least change the timing at which you can hover back dropdown area to very low value without changing overall menu transition timing. I'm trying to make dropdown show only on li:hover action.

Demo menu:
http://jsfiddle.net/q7gFR/

```
#cssmenu,#cssmenu ul,#cssmenu ul li,#cssmenu ul li a {
-webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
-o-transition: all ease .3s;
-moz-transition: all ease .3s;
-ms-transition: all ease .3s;
transition: all ease .3s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit (As you commented) : Answer is **NO**, you cannot get this behavior fixed unless you take out the `transition` and initiate it on `:hover`

---

Use the `transition` property on `:hover` so that when you `:hover` out, it will just disappear in a flick without any `transition`..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q7gFR/1/) (Increased on `:hover` time just for demonstration purpose)

Comment: yes it works, but the question was to know if it is possible without changing menu transition effects